# Creating Report using field installed by Application

Tags: reporting, custom-field, appexchange

I'm trying to Report off a field that was installed by a 3rd party application but it doesn't appear in the list of fields in Reports. There are two other custom fields apart from the 3rd party application's fields that do appear, but the one that I need does not. Any ideas on how I can make it appear? I've already checked the field level security for the field and it is indeed enabled to be viewed by my user profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to add the fields to the custom report type. See: [Why are some expected fields not visible when creating a Custom Report Type?](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000005196&language=en_US)

Comment: I've followed the steps and added it but when I actually try to create the report, I don't see the field listed.

Comment: You are sure that you saved after editing the report type field layout? 
And that you created a report of the same report type that you edited? 
And you tried using the search box to find the field, instead of just eye balling it? 
Sorry for all the questions, just not sure what the problem could be from what you have said.

Comment: I am sure that it's being saved and I'm using the search box to look for the field. No issues about the questions, these checkpoints are more than welcome.